# React-Calendly package not updating events through webhook

Tags: reactjs, calendly

I embedded Calendly in my application with the use of the react-calendly package.  It schedules the events like it should, however, it does not seem to trigger the webhook that I have set up.  When I use the embedded page supplied on Calendly's site it all works fine.  Is there something else that I need to set up in order for the webhooks to work?

I can provide additional information as needed but am not even sure what the root of this issue is.